# How to filter Fabric Answers' Events by LevelName

Tags: ios, analytics, twitter-fabric

I have implemented Events' tracking within Fabric with Answers.

I track properly `LevelEnd` and `LevelStart` get the correct data into Fabric's dashboard, BUT I don't see **how to filter my data by** `LevelName` or by `success == false`, etc in the dashboard, is that even possible ? I get the % rate of success = true and false, but that's the TOTAL and not per `LevelName`

[image]

```
Answers.logLevelStart("Level-\(self.currentLevel.rawValue)", customAttributes: ["levelTime" : self.levelTime])

Answers.logLevelEnd("Level-\(self.currentLevel.rawValue)", score: nil, success: false, customAttributes: ["levelTime" : levelTime, "totalEnnemy" : totalEnnemies, "remainEnnemies" : remainEnnemies])

Answers.logLevelEnd("Level-\(self.currentLevel.rawValue)", score: NSNumber(value: timerValue), success: true, customAttributes: ["levelTime" : levelTime, "totalEnnemy" : totalEnnemies, "remainEnnemies" : remainEnnemies])
```

Comment: you need to select and deselect check box as per your filter requirement .

Comment: yeah that what i thought, but it only filters the graph above, I looked if something else as changed but not :/

Comment: is it solve your problem ?

Comment: Nah, as said, I need to filter my LeveLName by success = true or false.